# Are type selectors supposed to be overridden by id selectors

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am new to Web Programming and I was playing around with adding different styles to different div containers using CSS styles and HTML. I copied an existing id selector called "box-1" and created a new one named "box-2" with a different color (red) and background color (yellow). When I applied this style to a new div, the paragraph color didn't match the color defined in the id selector but instead used the color from a paragraph type selector that I had added earlier(blue). The "box-1" paragraph color isn't right either.

```css
.box {
  border: 1px solid black;
  min-height: 250px;
}


/*I think this is overriding the id selector*/

p {
  color: blue;
}


/* This is a style I want to apply*/

#box-1 {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}


/* This is a style I want to apply*/

#box-2 {
  color: red;
  background-color: yellow;
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
  p {
    color: red
  }
}
```

```html
<div style="border: 1px solid black">
  <h1>Hello!</h1>
</div>
<div class="box">
  <p>Blah blah</p>
  <p>Blah blah</p>
  <h2>Sub section</h2>
</div>
<div class="box" id="box-1">
  <p>Blah blah</p>
  <p>Blah blah</p>
  <h2>Sub section</h2>
</div>
<div class="box" id="box-2">
  <p>Blah blah</p>
  <p>Blah blah</p>
  <h2>Sub section</h2>
</div>
```

Output:

[image]

I looked into css specificity, and from all I could gather, id selectors are supposed to override type selectors, so I'm not sure what the problem is. Does anyone know what the error is here?

Comment: Could you please clarify "I applied a color, then a different color, but the color wasn't right and the color didn't match" ? Please _name_ the colors, which color is supposed to go where?

Comment: `id` wins in case there is `class` as well

Comment: The `id` *on the `div`* does not override the style defined *on the `p`* that is its child. If you add `id="box-1"` to a `p` instead of the `div`, it would override the style defined in the `p`.

Comment: I edited the question so hopefully it's a little clearer.

Comment: I tried out that solution and it seemed to work. Would I just have to do that for all existing p elements if I still wanted to keep the p type selector?